# For the django admin, how do I add a field to the User model and have it editable in the admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to understand the django admin better and at the same time, I'm trying to add one more field to the current user admin.  In models.py I've done

```
User.add_to_class('new_field', models.BooleanField(default=False))
```

and in admin.py I've got the following (with fieldsets basically just copied from django/contrib/auth/admin.py)

```
class AdjUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
  list_display  = UserAdmin.list_display + ('new_field',)
  list_filter   = UserAdmin.list_filter + ('new_field',)

  fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets
  fieldsets[1][1]['fields'] = ('first_name','last_name','email','new_field')
```

The problem is, when I do this I get the error:

**`AdjUserAdmin.fieldsets[4][1]['fields']' refers to field 'new_field' that is missing from the form.`**

I've looked at UserChangeForm, but it looks like it's already correctly pulling in User as the model.  I'm not sure as to why `new_field` is missing from the form.

Thanks

**In regards to this being smelly code**

I know this is a smelly monkey patching way to go about doing this, but subclassing gives me issues mainly for [these](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/feb/20/about-model-subclassing/) reasons.. if I could get it to work the way stated above, I'd be happy.. and maybe smelly.

**In regards to the recommended way**

I'm aware of the recommended way of creating a user profile, just that in particular situations, I don't see the merit in creating an entire new table and having an additional call to the database when all I want to store is an extra bit of information such as `is_private` or some such.  If I'm storing lots more info, then I agree, setting up a user profile is preferable.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First the "is it plugged in?" question -- Have you manually added new_field to the users table in the database? Syncdb wouldn't have taken care of that, of course.

After that, I would try appending the fields onto the existing UserAdmin rather than rebuilding it from scratch:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

UserAdmin.list_display += ('new_field',)  # don't forget the commas
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('new_field',)
UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('new_field',)
```

Comment: Hmm.. dunno why I didnt think of that after using list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ('new_field',).. thanks!

Comment: When i use:
UserAdmin.list_display += ('nickname',)
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('nickname',)
UserAdmin.fieldsets += ('nickname',)
 <----->
there is something wrong, like this:<class 'django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E008) The value of 'fieldsets[4]' must be a list or tuple.
<----->
and i chang to :
UserAdmin.list_display += ('nickname',)
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('nickname',)
UserAdmin.fieldsets += (('nickname', {'fields': ('nickname',)}),)
<----->
this problem is gone.

Comment: @bovenson You can do it this way 
UserAdmin.fieldsets += (('Extra Fields', {'fields': ('new_field', )}),)

Answer (score 6):

Just figured this out, perhaps this could help you as well.

Since you don't mention that you have a separate profile, if you want to simply add a column to the existing User admin, you can do the following in `admin.py`:

First you create a custom admin by subclassing `UserAdmin`:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ('is_complete',)

    def is_complete(self, obj):
        # Example here, you can use any expression.
        return SomeOtherClass.objects.get(my_field=obj).is_complete()

    # Not required, but this gives you a nice boolean field:
    is_complete.boolean = True
```

Then unregister the existing `UserAdmin` and register your own:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is preferred to write your own user profile class, and attach it to the User model. Then you can use the `get_profile()` method to retrieve the profile from the user.

Subclassing the profile admin from an Inline Admin should also allow you to edit the profile on the user's page, which is almost what you're trying to do.

This post has a really good write-up on the issue: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/

Answer (score 3):

Based on @anschauung response, what worked for me in Django 3.2 is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

# don't forget the commas
UserAdmin.list_filter += ('new_field',)
UserAdmin.fieldsets +=  (('Extra Fields', {'fields': ('new_field', )}),)
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite your DB look up concerns for having a UserProfile, that is really the way you should go for this problem.  There are two main reasons for this:

1. The User Model is pretty tightly coupled to Django's authentication system and to many other plugins.  Monkey patching it isn't a good idea.
2. Django has built-in support for creating User Profiles and many extensions know how to play nicely with these.  By using User Profiles (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users for the main discussion on this) you can benefit from that.

If you're looking to add functionality to the Admin interface for users, then this note may be helpful:

http://www.thenestedfloat.com/articles/displaying-custom-user-profile-fields-in-djangos-admin/index.html

Regards,

Ian

Answer (score -1):

I got the 'that is missing from the form' error, and discovered that it was due to my field being marked as 'editable=False' in the model.