# Can small changes be made to the built-in registration and login system?

Tags: django, django-forms

So Django's built in registration, login, and database fit everything almost everything I need for my application, however, I need a boolean parameter in the database to determine if a user has permission to do something. Am I able to add this to the database while still being able to use the built-ins?

Comment: Django's authentication system has already permissions, permissions are added to groups, and users can be added to these groups. So a user has a permission if it is added to at least one group with that permission. This is a more extendable way than a boolean, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Comment: Well you can extend User model to add extra fields  take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478191/django-how-to-add-an-extra-field-in-user-model-and-have-it-displayed-in-the-adm/54305092#54305092 and if you found it useful then don't forget to upvote it :)